# how to apply global backgroundColor using MuiCssBaseline and styleOverrides

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I want to add global backgroundColor for the app where we use ThemeProvider. I see strange situation which I cannot figure out. Below in the picture You can see that body component don't "catch" whole components for the app, also please look at body props in devtools, backgroundColor and color (added for test) are different than I have added to the code below.Component with text:"Wybierz koło..." is rendered conditionally, that's why I want to make backgroundColor property globally to cover such situations.

[image]

This is how MainTheme is built :

```
 components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
        styleOverrides: {
            '@global': {
                html: {
                    fontSize: '62.5%' /* 62.5% of 16px = 10px */,
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins, sans-serif',
                },
                body: {
                    margin: '0',
                    color: 'red',
                    boxSizing: 'border-box',
                    fontFamily: 'Poppins, sans-serif',
                    backgroundColor: '#E3E3E3',
                },
            },
        },
    },
```

Here You can see how App component is biuld

```
export const App: FC = () => (
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <ThemeProvider theme={MainTheme}>
        <SCThemeProvider theme={MainTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Router>
                <AuthContextProvider>
                    <Notifications />
                    <RoutingManager />
                </AuthContextProvider>
            </Router>
        </SCThemeProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

);

This conditional component is rendered based on displayTooltipText

```
<StyledTable {...getTableProps()}>
                        {displayTooltipText ? (
                            <tbody>
                                <StyledTextWrapper>
                                    {selectWheelText}
                                </StyledTextWrapper>
                            </tbody>
                        ) : (
                            <TableBody
                                getTableBodyProps={getTableBodyProps}
                                prepareRow={prepareRow}
                                rows={rows}
                            />
                        )}
                    </StyledTable>
```

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `'@global': {` wrapper layer. You can see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.0/packages/mui-material/src/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js#L36) how the default styles are defined and overrides need to be [defined in the same way](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.0/packages/mui-material/src/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js#L47). Those styles (the defaults plus your overrides), then get passed to the [GlobalStyles component](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.5.0/packages/mui-material/src/CssBaseline/CssBaseline.js#L63) which handles the global scoping.

Here's a working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        html: {
          fontSize: "62.5%" /* 62.5% of 16px = 10px */,
          fontFamily: "Poppins, sans-serif"
        },
        body: {
          margin: "0",
          color: "red",
          boxSizing: "border-box",
          fontFamily: "Poppins, sans-serif",
          backgroundColor: "#E3E3E3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div>Hello World</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit CssBaseline Material Demo]