# Overwrite Material UI 5.0 typography theme globally with custom fonts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm attempting to use two personal fonts in `Material Ui 5.0` at the moment. I'd like to  apply them globally by overwriting the `theme`.
My first issue is that I can't get the fonts to even load properly, and I can't change the `typography` at all.
Furthermore, with `MUI 5.0`, I am unable to have this custom font applied to the full body section.
So if use   `<Typography variant='h4'>. or <Box>...</Box>` my custom fonts are not applying.
They way I did the global overwrite in `Mui 4.0` is not working anymore in version 5.
I'm very annoyed because the `MUI 5.0 documentation` does not properly or at all explain this, and I have been sitting there for hours.

I would appreciate any help !

I am using `React, Typescript`.

font.d.ts

```
 declare module '*.woff'
 declare module '*.ttf'
```

cssBaseLine.ts

```
import CustomOneMediumWoff from '../fonts/CustomOne-Medium.woff'
import CustomOneTwomWoff from '../fonts/CustomOne-Twom.woff'

    export const CssBaseline = {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
          
            // '@global': {
            //     html: {
            //       fontFamily: 'CustomOneTwomWoff',
            //       height: '100%',
            //       overflow: 'auto',
            //     },
            //     body: {
            //       fontFamily: 'CustomOneTwomWoff',
            //       height: '100%',
            //       overflow: 'auto',
            //     },
            //     '#root': {
            //       height: '100%',
            //       overflow: 'auto',
            //     },
            //   },
    
        // I did that in MUI 4.0 and it does not work anymore
      // Tho documentation is not explaining the global overwirte part anymore
    
        styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
            font-family: "CustomOne";
            url(${CustomOneMediumWoff}) format("woff"),
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
          }, 
    
          @font-face {
            font-family: "CustomTwo";
            url(${CustomTwoMediumWoff}) format("woff"),
            font-weight: 500;
            font-style: normal;
          }, 
    
      `,
      },
    }
    
    export default CssBaseline
```

typography.ts  fonts are not applying

```
export const typography = {
  fontFamily: ['CustomOne', 'CustomtTwo'].join(','),
  h1: {
    fontFamily: 'CustomOne',
    fontWeight: 500,
  },
  h2: {
    fontFamily: 'CustomOne',
  },
  h3: {
    fontFamily: 'CustomOne',
  },
  h4: {
    fontFamily: 'CustomOne',
  },
  button: {
    fontFamily: 'CustomtTwo',
  },
}

export default typography
```

theme.ts

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette:palette,
  typography: typography,
  components: {
    ...CssBaseline,
  },
})

export default theme
```

Does not work and default browser fonts are loaded

```
     <Typography variant='h4'>Test 4</Typography>
     <Box mt={4}>test Boxssssss H</Box>
```

App.tsx

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
....
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not seeing any obvious problem with the code in your question, but here is a working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import InspirationTTF from "./Inspiration-Regular.ttf";

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Inspiration"
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        "@font-face": {
          fontFamily: "Inspiration",
          src: `url(${InspirationTTF}) format("truetype")`
        },
        body: {
          fontSize: "3rem",
          color: "purple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Typography variant="h1">Hello World</Typography>
      <div>Some body text</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit custom font-family]

Related answer: [how to apply global backgroundColor using MuiCssBaseline and styleOverrides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468213/how-to-apply-global-backgroundcolor-using-muicssbaseline-and-styleoverrides/71469625#71469625)

Comment: Ok thanks Man ! I think the array was the problem. But I still do not understand how to override the body default font-family. E.g if I do not use Typography and just write a Text between two Box.

Comment: styleOverrides: `  @font-face {
          font-family: "Inspiration";
          src: url(${InspirationTTF}) format("truetype");
        }   body: {
        font-family: "Inspiration"; 
      }
      ` is not working

Comment: Setting `theme.typography.fontFamily` (as in my example) takes care of body text (as long as CssBaseline is used). The `div` in my example shows that working.

Comment: @maxfromgermany I've added some additional styling (font-size and color) of body text to my example.

Comment: Only allows one instance of `@font-face` but as like OP, I have 2 custom local fonts. Error: "An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name." Using TypeScript.

Comment: This saved me for 1 year for looking for solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are importing `createTheme` and `ThemeProvider` from `'@mui/material/styles'`.

Comment: To improve your answer, you could add code examples.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for Mui v5:

```
import AbradeRegular from 'assets/fonts/Abrade-Regular.ttf'
import AbradeMedium from 'assets/fonts/Abrade-Medium.ttf'
....

const abradeRegular = {
  fontFamily: 'Abrade',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 'normal',
  src: `url(${AbradeRegular}) format('truetype')`,
}

const abradeMedium = {
  fontFamily: 'Abrade',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: 500,
  src: `url(${AbradeMedium}) format('truetype')`,
}
....

theme.components = {
  MuiCssBaseline: {
    styleOverrides: {
      html: [
        {'@font-face': abradeLight},
        {'@font-face': abradeRegular},
        {'@font-face': abradeMedium},
        {'@font-face':abradeSemiBold},
        {'@font-face': abradeBold},
        {'@font-face':abradeExtraBold},
        {'@font-face':abradeBlack}
      ],
      'html, body': {
        padding: 0,
        scrollbarWidth: 'thin',
      },
}}}
```